# Cant get text box and links to the bottom of a div

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a text box and a few links to settle at the bottom next to a tall image, but dont seem to be having any luck. I've posted an Image and uploaded my file for you to see. I've tried all kinds of solutions from here that suggested setting the parent div to position:relative and giving the child div a position absolute. But nothing seems to be working. Can you please help me.

[image: Sample page]

My css files: https://sizablesend.com/90kdo8/StackExchange.rar#cid=14

Comment: what about using absolute positioning?

Comment: Like what I said in my question? Setting the parent div to position:relative and giving the child div a position: absolute. I tried everything, and finally came here.

Comment: absolute positioning should always work can you provide more code

Comment: I check your fiddle and it's really nice. More code? All I have is in that zip file.

Comment: dont forget to upvote :p

Answer (score 1):

you will need a wrapper for this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="img"></div>
    <div id="links">link1 link2</div>
</div>
```

this css will look like this:

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    top:5px;
    left:50px;
    height:50px;        
}
#img {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
#links {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

i used div so you will have to set display:inline-block that they stay in the same line

edit:

here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7Gs7/)

Comment: How can I set the wrappers margins to auto?